# Replacing the output value after a select T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, case

I have a query that selects records from two different databases. My query works and it displays the data that I want, but the stakeholder would like a specific field to be turned into a different answer so that they don't have to manipulate this row in Excel after they receive their SSRS report.

For this question I have changed the table names etc. and made the query simpler (mine contains a lot more columns), but the general concept is the same.

Tables: `tLive1`, `tCodes`

```
SELECT
        tLive1.cClientName AS 'Client Name'
       ,tLive1.cPolicynum AS 'Policy Number'
       ,tCodes.nStatus AS 'Status'

FROM tLive1 WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN tCodes WITH (NOLOCK) ON tLive1.nStat = tCodes.nStatus

WHERE tLive1.nStat LIKE 'In Progress'

ORDER BY 'Client Name'
```

My problem is that `tCodes.nStatus` has an internal description that sales doesn't want others to see and they rather turn say a 'In Progress' into 'Working' and so on.

I tried by using CASE, but I don't know where to insert the CASE without causing an error.

I tried this:

```
SELECT
        tLive1.cClientName AS 'Client Name'
       ,tLive1.cPolicynum AS 'Policy Number'
       --,tCodes.nStatus AS 'Status'
       ,( SELECT CASE nStatus
         WHEN 'Assigned' THEN 'Someone has it'
         ELSE 'XXX'
         END AS 'Status'
         FROM tCodes
        )


FROM tLive1 WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN tCodes WITH (NOLOCK) ON tLive1.nStat = tCodes.nStatus

WHERE tLive1.nStat LIKE 'In Progress'

ORDER BY 'Client Name'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your case statement directly in the select like this:

```
SELECT tLive1.cClientName AS 'Client Name',
    tLive1.cPolicynum AS 'Policy Number',
    CASE WHEN tCodes.nStatus = 'In Progress' THEN 'Working' 
        WHEN tCodes.nStatus = 'Assigned' THEN 'Someone has it' 
        ELSE tCodes.nStatus END  AS 'Status'
FROM tLive1 WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN tCodes WITH (NOLOCK) ON tLive1.nStat = tCodes.nStatus
WHERE tLive1.nStat LIKE 'In Progress'
ORDER BY 'Client Name'
```

You can Add as many WHEN statements to cover all of the conversions that are needed.

Comment: Worked like a charm Laney, thank you so much. I had to add:

 ELSE CAST (tcodes.nStatus AS CHAR(1)) because if not I was getting a tinyint error, but after that and your solution I am now in the clear. 

A million thanks.

Comment: @RogelioHernandez, press the "Accept" button to guide future users to this helpful answer and also to give credit where due.